# Filling in missing data in excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a couple thousand lines of data in excel. In one column, however, only every fifth line is filled. What I'm trying to do is fill in the four empty lines below each filled line with the data from the line above. I have a beginner's grasp of python, so if someone could steer me in the right direction, it would be a great help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: openpyxl can help you.

Comment: Either use the package suggested, or at least provide us with a sample of your data and your attempt at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, this seems easy enough to do in Excel:

Assume `row 1` contains column headers, and data begin in `row 2`. If `column A` contains your values (starting in `A2`), in cell `B2` use the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A2), B1, A2)` and fill down. This formula will return the value of `A2` if it is not blank, and will return the previous value in `column B` if the current value in `column A` is blank.

Note that this requires that the **first** cell in each group contains the value that you want to fill down.

A post-script for general reference: Excel has a hard time with blank cells resulting from formulas, so the *formula* `=""` (or the result of something like `=IFERROR(..., "")`) is **not blank**, but does have a length of 0. Changing `ISBLANK(A2)` to `LEN(A2)<1` accounts for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Should be an easy fix with vba (though you could even do something similar with a created column and an Excel formula):

```
Sub FillIn()
    Dim intLast As Integer, intColumn As Integer
    intLast = 100 'your last row'
    intColumn = 5 'the column missing data'
    For i = 2 To intLast 'assume 2 because of headers'
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, intColumn)) Then Cells(i, intColumn).Value = Cells(i - 1, intColumn).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Just replace intLast and intColumn values as your values.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to accomplish updating Excel data with Python:

**CSV module**

Save Excel data as csv. Import into Python as a tuple, list, or dictionary using [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv). Then, iterate through list's items, then add needed data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

with open('C:\Path\To\ExcelDataFile.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = []
    for row in csvReader:
         data.extend(row)

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
         if data[i][colnum] != None:
             data[i + 1][colnum] = <somevalue>   
             data[i + 2][colnum] = <somevalue>
             data[i + 3][colnum] = <somevalue>
             data[i + 4][colnum] = <somevalue>
```

**Pandas dataframe**

Import Excel data into a Python [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframe. Then, search for particular rows by index, then add needed data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\Path\ToExcel\DataFile.xlsx', 'ExcelSheetName')
for i, row in df.iterrows()
    if df.loc[i, colnum] != None :
       df.loc[i + 1, column] = <somevalue>     
       df.loc[i + 2, colnum] = <somevalue>
       df.loc[i + 3, colnum] = <somevalue>
       df.loc[i + 4, colnum] = <somevalue>
```

**Excel macro**

Script an Excel macro to clean the data as needed and have Python run the macro prior to import. Or simply run the macro in Excel and import final data into Python using aforementioned options.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import win32com.client

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Path\ToMacroEnabled\ExcelData.xlsm")
xl.Application.Run("ExcelData.xlsm!macroname.macroname")
...
```